# How can this allocation of bi-dimensional arrays work?

Tags: c, array, malloc

I was seeing this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326547/is-it-safe-to-use-variable-length-arrays) on StackOverflow and saw a new way (at least for me) to define a two dimensional array of 5x5, it works well, but I feel I don't understand what is going on in the background.

The code is.

```
double (*matrix)[5] = malloc(5 * sizeof *matrix);
```

How can this define a two dimensional array of 5x5?, before I thought that n mallocs were necessary to produce a n-dimensional array, but apparently I was wrong.

Comment: Why do I have downvotes?, at least explain what do you wan't me to fix on the question.

Comment: this is too much of an implementation question for this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matrix` is a pointer to a 5-element array of `double`; this means that the type of the *expression* `*matrix` is "5-element array of `double`"; `sizeof *matrix` will return the number of bytes required by such an object.

So we're telling `malloc` to set aside enough memory for 5 5-element arrays of `double`, and assign the resulting pointer to `matrix`.

Because of how pointer arithmetic works, `matrix` points to the first 5-element array, `matrix + 1` points to the second 5-element array, `matrix + 2` points to the third 5-element array, etc.

Since `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a + i)`, the expression `matrix[i]` gives us the `i`'th 5-element array, so `matrix[i][j]` gives us the `j`'th element of the `i`'th 5-element array.